# Laravel pagination with relation

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

This is the code that I have:

```
public function divisions(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->get('q');

    return Division::where('name', 'like', "%$q%")
            ->with(['nation' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'name');

            }])->simplePaginate();
}
```

And return the following:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "1",
    "classify": 1,
    "nation_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-05-08 09:00:00",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-08 09:00:00",
    "nation": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "France"
    }
}
```

But I need the following. What can I do to only return the following?

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "1",
    "nation": "France"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using it to build an API, you can use [Eloquent API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources), so can use it as the following:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'nation' => $this->nation->name,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I did not know this functionality and it helped me to solve the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

Try below given answer I think that will help you to achieve your problem solution.

**Solution 1:**

```
public function divisions(Request $request)
{
    $string = $request->get('q');
    $builder = new Division;
    $builder->where('name', LIKE, "%$string%")
            ->with(['nation' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'name');
            }]);

    $result = $builder->selectRaw("id, name, nation.name as nation")->simplePaginate();

    return response()->json($result);
}
```

**Solution 2**

**In Controller**

```
public function divisions(Request $request)
{
    $string = $request->get('q');
    $builder = new Division;
    $builder->where('name', LIKE, "%$string%")
            ->with(['nation' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'name');
            }]);

    $paginator = $builder->paginate();

    $data = fractal()
                ->collection($paginator->getCollection(), new DivisionsTransformer, 'divisions')
                ->serializeWith(new DataArraySerializer())
                ->paginateWith(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($paginator))
                ->toArray();
}
```

**DivisionsTransformers**

```
public function transform($resource)
{
    return [
        'id' => $resource->id,
        'name' => $resource->name,
        'nation' => $resource->nation->name,

    ];
}
```

Here is the reference of transformers library. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal

Comment: With the first solution `"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nation.name' in 'field list' (SQL: select id, name, nation.name as nation from `divisions` limit 16 offs ▶"`

Comment: Can you please share the full SQL query